# How to send message using email address on twitter

Tags: twitter, marketplace

I have list of emails. And want to send a market campaign through messages on twitter. How it can be done using email list.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, as there's no way to look up Twitter accounts via email address in the Twitter API.

Comment: Hi @Andy. Thanks for the response. Is there any alternate way to do it?